# MultiIndex Slicing with a Timeseries Row Index

Tags: python, pandas

I used the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078463/selecting-sublevels-of-multiindex-columns-in-pandas/33078570#33078570) to try to make a similar slice on my dataframe.  But it doesn't seem to work because my row index is a TimeSeries. I am not sure how to rephrase the slice to work.

The df I'm using has a single TimeSeries index, and the columns are a two-level MultiIndex.  I'm attempting to, for an arbitrary row, to return a series of consisting of the "px" subcolumn of each major column.
[image]

The first attempt: `df.loc[0,(slice(None), 'px')]` throws a TypeError,

```
TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <type 'int'>
```

So I also have tried to feed it a DateTime for the index, instead of an int:

```
useIndex = sdf.index[0]
return df.loc[useIndex,(slice(None), 'px')]
```

Which gives a:

```
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

Postscript...

If I just do a simple,

```py
useIndex = sdf.index[0]
useIndex
sdf.iloc[useIndex]
```

I get the failure:

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [2015-10-08 00:00:00] of <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

So maybe the problem is that I'm not really passing a valid index to the MultiIndex slice?

================

Here are two examples:  The first df ('df') I'm able to pull out the data I want.  The second df, ('df2') throws a Type Error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = [['col_1', 'col_2'], ['delta', 'px']]
multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(cols, names= ["level_0", "level_1"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20).reshape(5, 4), index=range(5), columns=multi_idx)

row_number =1 

print df.loc[df.index[row_number], pd.IndexSlice[:, 'px']]

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20).reshape(5, 4), index=rng, columns=multi_idx)

#print df2.loc[df.index[row_number], pd.IndexSlice[:, 'px']]
useIndex = df2.index[0] 

print df2.loc[useIndex, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'px']]
```

Comment: Instead of putting an image to your dataframe, you should directly copy/paste the dataframe here. It would make it easier for others to copy the dataframe and use `pd.read_clipboard()` , to reproduce your issue and test it out.

Comment: Anand S Kumar.  I've "copied and pasted" the fragment of the dataframe, but it just ends up as gibberish in a stackoverflow window.

Comment: After copy pasting, you should use the `{}` icon to make it into a code block, so that it does not become gibberish

Comment: Anand S Kumar, there you go, copied from my terminal, pasted and marked'up as code.

Comment: what are you expecting as output?

Comment: Also, in your second case, did you try - `sdf.loc[useIndex]` - instead of `iloc` ?

Comment: use `print(df.to_string())` in an ipython notebook to get something a little more stackoverflow-friendly. you're not doing yourselves an favors by not having a self-contained, working example.

Comment: `df.iloc[:5, :6].to_dict()` would print the first 5 rows and six columns of your dataframe in dictionary output which should be sufficient for others to recreate your issue.

Comment: I added a short segment of script that creates two different data frames (one w/ integer index, the other with timeSeries index). I'm able to query the integer-index dataframe ok, but cannot query the timeSeries index dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IndexSlice` should help get your desired results.  Note that the columns first need to be lex sorted:

```
cols = [['col_1', 'col_2'], ['delta', 'px']]
multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(cols, names= ["level_0", "level_1"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20).reshape(5, 4), index=range(5), columns=multi_idx)

>>> df
level_0     col_1               col_2          
level_1     delta        px     delta        px
0        0.891758  0.071693  0.629897  0.693161
1        0.772542  0.022781  0.684584  0.892641
2        0.925957  0.794940  0.146950  0.134798
3        0.159558  0.842898  0.677927  0.028675
4        0.436268  0.989759  0.471879  0.101878

row_number = 3
>>> df.loc[df.index[row_number], pd.IndexSlice[:, 'px']]
level_0  level_1
col_1    px         0.842898
col_2    px         0.028675
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi.  The example here works, but the issue is that if the index is a DateTime index, df.loc returns a Type Error   rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20).reshape(5, 4), index=rng, columns=multi_idx)

print df2.loc[df.index[row_number], pd.IndexSlice[:, 'px']]

Comment: Works for me on Pandas 0.16.2.  Note your inconsistent usage of `df` in your comment.  Should be `df2.loc[df2.index...`